# Indexing a Dataframe in steps of 0.5

Tags: python, pandas

I have several dataframes that I want to add. Theyre indices range from 0 to 25 in steps of 0.5. Now, when I try to add them, the indices are interpreted differently and the new added dataframe has the indices ordered from "0 to 2" its 0.5,1,1.5,10,10.5...19.5, 2....etc. So that 10 is listed lower than 2, I guess because it starts with a 1 and the dataframe sorts the indices by the first value.

I tried different ways of adding the frames:

```py
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3...], axis=0)
df1 + df2 + df3
df1.add(df2, fill_value=0).add(df3.....)
```

all of them work. The only problem is the new indexing which messes up my frames.

I could of course reset the indices before adding the frames and then change the index back. But is there a more direct way?

answer to comment:

```
Index(['0.5', '1.0', '1.5', '2.0', '2.5', '3.0', '3.5', '4.0', '4.5', '5.0',
       '5.5', '6.0', '6.5', '7.0', '7.5', '8.0', '8.5', '9.0', '9.5', '10.0',
       '10.5', '11.0', '11.5', '12.0', '12.5', '13.0', '13.5', '14.0', '14.5',
       '15.0', '15.5', '16.0', '16.5', '17.0', '17.5', '18.0', '18.5', '19.0',
       '19.5', '20.0', '20.5', '21.0', '21.5', '22.0', '22.5', '23.0', '23.5',
       '24.0', '24.5', '25.0', '25.5', '26.0', '26.5', '27.0', '27.5', '28.0',
       '28.5'],
      dtype='object') Index(['0.5', '1.0', '1.5', '2.0', '2.5', '3.0', '3.5', '4.0', '4.5', '5.0',
       '5.5', '6.0', '6.5', '7.0', '7.5', '8.0', '8.5', '9.0', '9.5', '10.0',
       '10.5', '11.0', '11.5', '12.0', '12.5', '13.0', '13.5'],
      dtype='object') Index(['0.5', '1.0', '1.5', '2.0', '2.5', '3.0', '3.5', '4.0', '4.5', '5.0',
       '5.5', '6.0', '6.5', '7.0', '7.5', '8.0', '8.5', '9.0', '9.5', '10.0',
       '10.5', '11.0', '11.5', '12.0', '12.5', '13.0', '13.5', '14.0', '14.5',
       '15.0', '15.5', '16.0', '16.5', '17.0', '17.5', '18.0'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Waht is `print (df1.index, df2.index, df3.index)` ?

Comment: I think you need something around .reset_index(), it should start like this
`df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3...], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Id like to keep the Indeces at half steps though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simpliest solution is convert index to `FloatIndex` in all DataFrames:

```
df1.index = df1.index.astype(float)
df2.index = df2.index.astype(float)
df3.index = df3.index.astype(float)
```